# x86 assembly - window does not show up yet no compile-time errors

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm32

I am trying to create a window in x86 assembly with masm32 using the `CreateWindowEx` API. I have gotten my code to have no compile-time errors or anything of the sort- it compiles just fine. Yet when I run the exe, nothing happens. I don't see any obvious errors, and I have practically copied the code out of Iczelion's Win32 Tutorial (Part 3 - A Simple Window). What is wrong with it?

Here is my code:

```
.386 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap :none 
WinMain proto :DWORD,:DWORD, :DWORD,:DWORD

include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib

.data 
ClassName db "Testwin", 0
AppName db "Testing Window", 0
.data?
hInstance HINSTANCE ?
CommandLine LPSTR ?
.code 
start: 

push NULL
call GetModuleHandle
mov  hInstance,eax
call GetCommandLine
mov CommandLine, eax
push SW_SHOWDEFAULT
push CommandLine
push NULL
push hInstance
call WinMain
push eax
call ExitProcess

WinMain proc hInst:HINSTANCE,hPrevInst:HINSTANCE, CmdLine:LPSTR,CmdShow:DWORD
; local vars:
LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX 
LOCAL msg:MSG 
LOCAL hwnd:HWND

; defining the window:
mov   wc.cbSize,SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX 
mov   wc.style, CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW 
mov   wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc 
mov   wc.cbClsExtra,NULL 
mov   wc.cbWndExtra,NULL 
push  hInst 
pop   wc.hInstance 
mov   wc.hbrBackground,COLOR_WINDOW+1 
mov   wc.lpszMenuName,NULL 
mov   wc.lpszClassName,OFFSET ClassName 
invoke LoadIcon,NULL,IDI_APPLICATION 
mov   wc.hIcon,eax 
mov   wc.hIconSm,eax 
invoke LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW 
mov   wc.hCursor,eax 
invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc 
;create the window
invoke CreateWindowEx,NULL,ADDR ClassName,ADDR AppName,\ 
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,\ 
       CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,NULL,NULL,\ 
       hInst,NULL
invoke ShowWindow,hwnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL
WinMain endp

WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
cmp uMsg, WM_DESTROY
jne _next
invoke PostQuitMessage, NULL
_next:

WndProc endp
end start
```

Where have I gone wrong? I suspect it has something to do with `CreateWindowEx`, considering it takes 12 parameters, most of which I don't understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have not assigned the window handle returned by `CreateWindowEx` to the `hwnd` variable.

So add the following line after `invoke CreateWindowEx` and before `invoke ShowWindow` -

```
mov hwnd, eax
```

Comment: It still didn't show up any window when I placed that line there.

Comment: It would be good to do some error checking on the return values of the APIs. So after each invoke, check the value of `eax` for error conditions. Another thing you could do is to handle the `WM_CREATE` message in `WndProc` and set `eax` to 0 - `xor eax, eax`.

Answer (score 0):

1. We do not compile anything when using Assebmly!  We Assemble and Link.
2. This is not C or any other high level language, you do not need WinMain.
3. The biggie, where is your message loop

After your CreateWindowEx and ShowWindow, you need something like this right after that:

```
.while TRUE
    invoke GetMessage,addr msg,NULL,0,0
  .break .if !eax
    ;invoke IsDialogMessage,hModelessDialog,addr msg
    ;.if !eax
        ;invoke TranslateAccelerator,hWnd,hAccel,addr msg
        ;.if !eax
            invoke TranslateMessage,addr msg
            invoke DispatchMessage,addr msg
        ;.endif
    ;.endif
.endw
```

You are also missing *ret* at the end of your procs